# Function that extracts each unique character in a string

Tags: r

Let's say that I have a string `"rrkn"`. Is there a function in R that'll return a vector `"r"`, `"k"`, `"n"` (i.e. each unique character in the string)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to make it slightly less cumbersome to type:

```
uniqchars <- function(x) unique(strsplit(x, "")[[1]])
```

Comment: `unique(unlist(strsplit(x, "")))` or `lapply(strsplit(x, ""), unique)` are more general ways to handle vector input (for anyone else landing on this Q that may not be looking at scalars only)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to use `rawToChar(unique(charToRaw(x)))`.

Comment: Well, this doesn't return a vector. Although it might be useful for some other cases.

Comment: This is likely to be more memory-efficient for general UTF-8 input if `x` has up to paragraphs of characters (since `strsplit()` will touch the global string cache, dumping 1000s or 1Ms of characters in there, only to be garbage-collected), but I also think it fails on multi-byte characters. YMMV

Answer (score 2):

A `stringr` option is:

```r
library(stringr)
str_unique(str_split_1("rrkn", ""))
```